# How to perform async continuous reading from socket instead of poll TcpClient with while(true)

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous

I'm working with an Access Control Device, that allows or denies access to rooms, verifying rights through biometric data. I need to listen indefinitely for data on a connected TcpClient(Socket). But how to do this without the following approach:

```
byte[] bb = new byte[1024]
while(true)
{
    if (tcpClient.Client.Available > 0)
    {
        tcpClient.Client.Receive(bb, bb.Length, SocketFlags.None);
        int k = tcpClient.Client.Receive(bb);
        string result = Encoding.Default.GetString(bb.Take(k).ToArray());
        // do sth here, rise an event, etc...
    }

    Thread.Sleep(500);
}
```

I'm following [this](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/CSharp/0580__Network/GUIbasedTcpClient.htm) example, did some adaptation (see below), but only the first chunk of data is read (if the device sends something again, the sent data are not read). I think that the EndReceive method is closing the socket or else, but I want to read the socket continuously, to raise an event every time socket reads data.

```
...
TcpClient tcpClient // Connected with BeginConnect
byte[] BufferData = new byte[1024]
public IAsyncResult StartReceivingData()
{
    //some code here
    return tcpClient.Client.BeginReceive(DataBuffer, 0, 
        DataBuffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, 
        new AsyncCallback(ReceivedData), tcpClient);
}

public void ReceivedData(IAsyncResult callerResult)
{
    TcpClient remote = (TcpClient)callerResult.AsyncState;
    int recv = remote.Client.EndReceive(callerResult);
    string stringData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(BufferDados, 0, recv);
    //rise an event here containing stringData
}
```

**EDIT**

I'm working with .NET 3.5 and I can't upgrade to .NET 4/4.5, because this is part of a legacy system.

Comment: I think you forgot to post the most interesting part of your async sample where you are starting new `BeginReceive`... Side note: consider is `async`/`awiat` (Net 4.5) would work for you as code will *look* much simple.

Answer (score 4):

TcpClient has a very useful method `GetStream`. I would use it.

```
var buf = new byte[0x10000];
var stream  = tcpClient.GetStream();
int len = await stream.ReadAsync(buf, 0, buf.Length);
while (len > 0)
{
    //your work ....
    len = await stream.ReadAsync(buf, 0, buf.Length);
}
```

If you are getting strings separated by newline chars, then you can also use this

```
var stream = new StreamReader(tcpClient.GetStream());
string line = await stream.ReadLineAsync();
while (line!=null)
{
    //...
    line = await stream.ReadLineAsync();
}
```

**EDIT**

`but only the first chunk of data is read` It is because `BeginReceive` doesn't mean you'll get a callback for every data you receive. You should call it everytime you receive your data (for ex, in *ReceivedData* method)

Comment: Thank you for answering, @EZI . I think that even using the "await" statement, I'll still block the thread with the while loop, and as I said, I want to avoid these loops.

Comment: @CezarLamann,  No it won't. This is the whole point in using async/await.  BTW: this is much better than *busy waiting* (`if (tcpClient.Client.Available > 0)` + `Thread.Sleep`)

Comment: @CezarLamann I think you have a blocking problem `but only the first chunk of data is read`. First solve it, than you can think about the next problem if you have any.

Comment: @EZI As I said: `I need to listen indefinitely for data on a connected TcpClient(Socket). But how to do this without the "while approach"`

Comment: @CezarLamann I say, this approach doesn't block any thread. So can you justify the reason `I don't want to use while-loop`. In this form, it seems just childish. *I don't want* ... *I don't wan't* ..... :)

Comment: @CezarLamann Just forget it, and don't use my answer. I leave it here just because someone else can get benefit of it.

Comment: @EZI Since I'm working with a legacy .NET 3.5 code, that can't be upgraded to .NET 4/4.5 (which have support for async/await (.NET 4 with Bcl)) for many reasons, I couldn't do that this way. I forgot to mention this in my previous comment. It's not for a "childish" reason. I've edited the question.

Comment: @CezarLamann -1 for taking time of people by not mentioning your requirements in question. Now I expect you to explain your reason for downvote.

Comment: @EZI Even before I mention about .NET Framework, you answered with something that I told I wouldn't use. Since I wrote I was using IAsync things instead of while loops (like you answered), why don't you answered aligned with the question?

Comment: @CezarLamann This is the reason for downvote? Then Noone should show  alternative ways to the question. Just post a code that OP thinks(with his limited knowledge) it is a solution to his problem.

Comment: @EZI Ok, you win. Edit it, I'll give your vote back.

Comment: @CezarLamann I am not interested in your -2 points (don't do it). But, since you didn't get any answer in 2 hours other than this, it think it is enough time for *redemption*